# Call reusable workflow conditionally from a job

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a reusable workflow that runs tests. I also have a `deploy` workflow that calls this workflow.

```
jobs:
  run-tests:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/build-and-test.yml

  deploy:
    needs: run-tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      ...
```

Is there a way to make the `run-tests` job be conditional on the event type? I tried putting `if: github.event_type != 'push'` before `uses:`, but that didn't work. To be clear, I always want the deployment job to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `event_name`

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:

jobs:

  docker:
    if: github.event_name != 'push'
    uses: kmadof/github-actions-manual/.github/workflows/so-041-reusable-workflow.yaml@main
    with:
      image_name: my-awesome-app
      tag: $GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER

  do-it:
    needs: docker
    if: (github.event_name == 'push' && needs.docker.result == 'skipped') || success()
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Run a one-line script
        run: |
            echo Hello, world!
            echo ${{ needs.docker.result }}
            echo ${{ github.event_name }}
            echo ${{ github.event_name != 'push' && needs.docker.result == 'skipped' }}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I needed to have the inverse check and also for 'skipped'.

Comment: @andrei could you consider mark my reply as answer if it helped you?

Comment: Yes, sorry, just did.